# Modify py2exe packed executable

Tags: python, patch-reversing

I have an application in Python compiled with py2exe.
I have successfully extracted python scripts using Py2ExeDumper converted to `.py` using Easy Python Decompiler.

I made some modification to the python code and recompiled `.py` files to `.pyc` files.

Question : How can I rebuild the exe file using the new edited `.pyc` files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to rebuild the EXE from the `.pyc` files, you can just use py2exe to build a new EXE from the modified `.py` files.

Alternatively, if you really want to *replace* the library in the original EXE, you would need to extract the EXE's `PYTHONSCRIPT` resource with a resource editor, un-marshal the array of code objects, replace the code object of your choosing in the array, re-marshal the array of code objects, and replace the `PYTHONSCRIPT` resource data with this new marshaled stream. You can look at `_create_script_data` in http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/py2exe-3/py2exe/runtime.py for more details.

Comment: This project is very big and have a lot of .pyc files. That's the reason why i am searching to replace the entire library in exe. There is a way to make setup.py for py2exe automatically from directory?

Comment: This point it's not clear: "replace the code object of your choosing in the array, re-marshal the array of code objects" can you explain more detailed please?

Comment: Questions related to writing Python code to handle arrays and marshal data should be asked on http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

A py2exe generated executable basically consists of three main parts - *PYTHONSCRIPT*, the runtime python dll & library.zip.

*PYTHONSCRIPT* can be modified with a decent resource editor. It is basically a marshalled array holding pyc files. The main script of the application is usually stored here.

In order to make changes you need to unmarshal the code objects, decompile it to *py*, make changes, recompile back to *pyc*, marshal it back to generate a new *PYTHONSCRIPT* and finally update the executable.

Modifying library.zip is easier as it is a standard zip file. It contains other *pyc/pyo* files. You can decompile them, make changes, recompile it back to *pyc/pyo*, and zip them up. Next replace the overlay in the executable with your new zip file and you are done.

In order to automate some of the above steps you can use a tool [Py2Exe Binary Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p2ebe/)

<sub>Note: I am the author of the above tool</sub>